# Using grunt to build bower components

Tags: gruntjs, bower

How do I configure my `Gruntfile` to run the build scripts for my `bower` components?

One issue is that each component may have a different build command, for example [D3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3) uses a `Makefile`, so I need to run `make`, and [angular.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js) also uses grunt and needs to run `grunt build`.

Can someone point me to an example of this?

Comment: What are you trying to build? Can you not just use the libs as-is?

Comment: What I would like to know is the general approach to running the build scripts for component libraries. For example, the angular.js library requires `grunt build` to create a single JS library file. Some components include the built files in the repository, and there exists separate repositories that contain builds, but I would like a general approach to build the components from the primary source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Bower components should be built.**

Otherwise users are going to be in the exact situation you're in. I know many components currently aren't, but there's not much we can do about it.

You can use [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) to easily execute whatever build scripts you need to:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    shell: {
        d3: {
            command: 'make',
            options: {
                execOptions: {
                    cwd: 'components/d3'
                }
            }
        },
        angular: {
            command: 'grunt',
            options: {
                execOptions: {
                    cwd: 'components/angular'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I have been using [Grunt Task for Bower](https://github.com/yatskevich/grunt-bower-task) to do the build.

You may find it useful.

After setup, you can copy all the required components in this way

```
grunt bower:install
```

Comment: yeah grunt-bower-install is another good tool: https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install